# Reading Files from JAR (NoSuchFileException)

Tags: java, unix, nio

I am trying to read a few files from a JAR file. The JAR file is located in the Tomcat's lib folder. I am reading the file like:

```
String filePath = DirectoryReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(directoryPath).getPath();

System.out.println("Directory Path: " + directoryPath);
System.out.println("File Path 1: " + filePath);

filePath = filePath.substring(6, filePath.indexOf("!"));

System.out.println("File Path 2: " + filePath);

Path configJARLocation = Paths.get(filePath);
System.out.println("JAR location: " + configJARLocation.toString());
InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(configJARLocation);
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
```

But I get an exception in the logs:

```
Directory Path: META-INF/gmm/xmlFiles/predefined/ipsec/
File Path 1: file:/opt/app/tools/tomcat/lib/appConfigurations.jar!/META-INF/gmm/xmlFiles/predefined/ipsec/
File Path 2: opt/app/tools/tomcat/lib/appConfigurations.jar
JAR location: opt/app/tools/tomcat/lib/appConfigurations.jar
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: opt/app/tools/tomcat/lib/appConfigurations.jar
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
        at com.gtc.logicalprovisioning.dac.file.DirectoryReader.process(DirectoryReader.java:72)
```

Other than the leading `/` in front of `opt`, I can't see anything that is incorrect. Line 72 of the code is:

```
InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(configJARLocation);
```

The same code is working in Windows. Its only when I deploy on my Unix environment, it starts to fail. I initially thought it was permission or access issue. But doesn't seem to be the case. I changed `chmod` from 755 first then to 777 for the JAR file. Then I changed the permission using `chown`. But it still didn't work. I am not a Unix expert, so I cant really dig much into this. Kindly advise! Thanks!

Comment: The `/` is very important! With it it's an absolute path and without it a relative one. In your case, you need an absolute path.

Comment: Print the `configJARLocation.toAbsolutePath()` value to understand this.

Comment: But shouldn't the API read the path with the `/` on its own rather than me doing string manipulation? I will give the toAbsolutePath() a try a see what it gives. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I found the problem... It is the `file:/` prefix. Since I am chopping the string from 6, it works on Windows. In Unix, rather than the prefix being `file://opt/...` its only `file:/opt/...` Hence the mix-up. In Windows, it appears as `file:/H:/tomcat/....`. The only solution I can think of now is to just detect the OS first and chop from 5 if its Unix like and 6 if its Windows.

Comment: There are no files in a JAR file. There are resources. You don't need most of this code, just `Class.getResource()` and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above in my comment.The problem was the `file:/` prefix. Since I was doing string manipulation, with the start index of `6`, it was causing the first `/` to get cut from the Unix path.

Windows Path is like:

```
file:/H:/...
```

Can't really say why the Windows path has an extra `/` in front. If anyone can enlighten me on it, that would be nice.

Unix Path is like:

```
file:/opt/...
```

So the cleaner option would be the use the URL/URI API to get it done. Should have thought of this earlier, as it is a more graceful way of tackling this.

```
// JAR File Reading
String filePath = DirectoryReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(directoryPath).getPath();

filePath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.indexOf("!"));

URL url = new URL(filePath);

Path configJARLocation = Paths.get(url.toURI());

InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(configJARLocation);
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
String filePath = DirectoryReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(directoryPath).getPath();
```

to this way

```
String filePath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile();
```